# regular expression match and discard multiline with specific html tag

Tags: html, regex, jsp

i have a little problem with matching html tag in jsp file when using regex.
i want to discard the comment line in jsp file and get the matching line.
here's my test html tag,

condition:
1. catch the comment line but not in the regex match group,
2. catch the line **just after** the comment line.

```

[Before]

```
<%--

  <img src="/x.gif" alt='x.gif'>
  <input type="text" name="x" value="y">
--%>
  <img src="/x.gif" alt='x.gif'>
  <input type="text" name="x" value="y">
```

[After]

```
  <img src="/x.gif" alt='x.gif'>
  <input type="text" name="x" value="y">
```

```

tks for help. :)

Comment: What features in the desired text are so special that you want to keep them... in other words what makes them different then other text that you don't want to match?

Comment: i want to use regex match multiline and i have a problem using ?: ?! match pattern, i dont know how to figuare it out. :<

Answer (score 0):

## Description

```regex
<%--((?:<\/?[a-z]+(?=[\s>])(?:[^>=]|=(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*"|[^'"\s]*))*\s?\/?>|[^<])*?)--%>
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

This regular expression will do the following:

- finds comments that bracketed inside `<%--` and `--%>` tags
- saves the entire contents of the comment tag to capture group 1
- avoids difficult edge cases that make pattern matching in HTML difficult

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/fH2xU5/3

**Sample text**

```
<span><a onmouseover=' if ( 3 > a ) { var string=" <img src=NotTheDroidYouAreLookingFor.jpg>; "; } ' href="link.html">This is a droid I'm looking for: <img src=DesiredDroids.png></a>
</span>

<%--

  <img onmouseover=' if ( 3 > a ) { var string=" --%> <img src=NotTheDroidYouAreLookingFor.jpg>; "; } ' src="/x.gif" alt='x.gif'>
  <input type="text" name="x" value="y">
--%>

No start comment tag

  <img src="/x.gif" alt='x.gif'>
  <input type="text" name="x" value="y">
--%>

<%--

  <img src="/x.gif" alt='x.gif'>
  <input type="text" name="x" value="y">
--%>
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [196-369]   `

  <img onmouseover=' if ( 3 > a ) { var string=" --%> <img src=NotTheDroidYouAreLookingFor.jpg>; "; } ' src="/x.gif" alt='x.gif'>
  <input type="text" name="x" value="y">
`

MATCH 2
1.  [481-557]   `

  <img src="/x.gif" alt='x.gif'>
  <input type="text" name="x" value="y">
```

## Explanation

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  <%--                     '<%--'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                             times (matching the least amount
                             possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      <                        '<'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [a-z]+                   any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 or
                               more times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [\s>]                    any character of: whitespace (\n,
                                 \r, \t, \f, and " "), '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible)):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        [^>=]                    any character except: '>', '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        =                        '='
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        (?:                      group, but do not capture:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          [^']*                    any character except: ''' (0 or
                                   more times (matching the most
                                   amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          '                        '\''
----------------------------------------------------------------------
         |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or
                                   more times (matching the most
                                   amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          "                        '"'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
         |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
          [^'"\s]*                 any character except: ''', '"',
                                   whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and "
                                   ") (0 or more times (matching the
                                   most amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
        )                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      )*                       end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s?                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
                               (optional (matching the most amount
                               possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      \/?                      '/' (optional (matching the most
                               amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      >                        '>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
     |                        OR
----------------------------------------------------------------------
      [^<]                     any character except: '<'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    )*?                      end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  --%>                     '--%>'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: oh my god...the tool and it's so professional, tks a lot.
but i want to discard the comment part of html.

Comment: ok, so you're looking to just drop the `<%--` and the `--%>` portions of the text while at the same time retain the text that is inside the comment tags?

Comment: sorry my bad expression,
i want to drop the line between <%-- and %--> and get the match just after the remark line.
ex.(single line)...it's much more easy for me..
i want to find the line class="msg" but has no id="msg" before or after it.
so i wrote reg to match :
(?!.*id="msg")^((.*)(class="msg"(\s*))>)(?!.*id="msg")
and i wrote the replace to add the id to match my need:
$2id="msg" $3$4>

Comment: Can you update your question to include both the sample text you'd like matched, and the text that you'd like after the replacement?

Comment: See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/kJ3bQ2/1) showing how to find the line with `class="msg"` without `id="msg"`.  The expression captures the entire comment block. Then replaces the entire block with the single line that has tag with both `class="msg"` and `id="msg"`.

Comment: I see your update to your question but there is no mention of the id or class requirements.

Comment: sorry for that, my bad question expression again @@  
that's just an example to explain,
the condition in class="msg" is, i want to find the line lack of "id="msg"   whatever it's at the beginning or end of line.

Comment: and the original question is.
i want to find the multiline match and it's start with the comment line, and it must have a specific html tag line just after the comment (multi)line.
thanks for your help and your time : )

Comment: Ok, so working on the original question, based on your sample text, you're looking to remove the comment block, but only if it contains the same text that is after the block?

Comment: it's ok if the text after the comment blocks are different.just match html tag between any <tag> and </tag> are ok :)